# Getting this error retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit

I made an API for login and register. It's working fine in Postman and I am getting the right responses, but when I hit the URL from my android app I am getting the error below.

I tried to find the solution on the internet but couldn't find one.

Please help me where I am getting wrong:

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.117/info/")    
             .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

The API interface:

```
  public interface Api {
      @POST("/Registers.php")
      Observable<Request<User>> savePost(@Body User user);   
  }
```

My calling code:

```
ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class)
    .savePost(new User("sad","asd","asd")) 
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Request<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() { }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Request<User> userRequest) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        }
    });
```

[image]

Logcat

```
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:43)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError$1.onNext(OperatorMapResponseToBodyOrError.java:38)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:80)
W/System.err:     at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
W/System.err:     at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
W/System.err:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
W/System.err:     at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:220)
W/System.err:     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: remove the `/` from `@POST("/Registers.php")` it should look like `@POST("Registers.php")`

Comment: still getting same error !

Comment: i think / is not a problem

Comment: could you please show the screenshot of postman with details which shows it's working. & Indeed that was one of the problem. You have already added `/` in base url. adding another `/` in Register.php is useless

Comment: Also I am sure you already have added Internet Permission in you manifest & as it seems you are testing with local host, make sure your mobile & computer are connected to the same network

Comment: yup i am testing it on emulator check the edited question

Comment: 8080 is default port I guess but still could you try by adding it in the base url like `http://192.168.1.117:8080/info/`

Comment: i tried that too same error :(

Comment: Are you sure that's your computer's IP address? You can always try with `10.0.2.2` (which is the computer's IP in the emulator's eyes)